# Como definir um timeout para determinada ação em Java?

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, session, jsp

Gostaria de definir um timeout para uma determinada ação em páginas JSP, sendo que deve funcionar com as seguintes condições abaixo:

1. Quando eu clicar em um botão por exemplo **"Viajar"**, a página deverá guardar de alguma forma o tempo de inicio e tempo final e dizer quanto tempo falta para chegar em determinado destino.
2. Quando eu não estiver na página, o tempo deverá continuar.
3. Quando eu entrar na página novamente, a página deve me mostrar quanto tempo restante falta para chegar em determinado destino de segundo em segundo.

**Fazendo uso disto:**

Para determinar o tempo que o usuário vai poder executar a mesma ação na aplicação Web novamente, pois deverá haver intervalos.

Comment: Você já fez algo? Poste o código do que você já tem ou de algo próximo que você tentou

Comment: Não desenvolvi nada ainda em relação ao timeout devido a falta de conhecimento de funções e maneiras de como chegar ao objetivo de acordo com as condições citadas.

Comment: Alguns pontos que você precisa definir é, como você vai identificar se a pessoa que saiu da tela vai ser a mesma que voltar. Tu pretende usar sessão? vai salvar algo em banco?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como definir um tempo de expiração em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70618/como-definir-um-tempo-de-expira%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-java)

Comment: Vou utilizar sessão sim, e também vou salvar a `hora_inicio`e `hora_final` para comparar na página se já deu o tempo... Porém quando efetuar essa comparação, tenho que ter o tempo restante sendo exibida na página de segundo em segundo, mostrando os minutos restantes sem ter que executar uma `query` de segundo em segundo.

Comment: @BrunoCésar estarei excluindo a pergunta citada, pois muitos usuarios estão entendendo que se trata apenas de uma sessão de usuário, e não é isso!

Comment: Oi Luiz Ricardo eu acho que sei o que você quer! Ainda quer excluir a pergunta? Posso tentar te ajudar. Acho que o que você precisa é de WebSockets + uma sessão so lado do servidor. Será que é isso? WebSockets tem esses poderes que você citou.

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo @FilipeGonzagaMiranda dei uma lida sobre o intuito do WebSockets e é realmente isso que eu quero, agora o desafio é fazer o uso desse cara... Você tem conhecimento do uso de WebSockets, onde posso achar um bom conteúdo que explica formas de utilizar?

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda faça o seguinte... responda a pergunta com um link de formas de usar WebSockets, e ai vou aceitar sua resposta como utilidade em relação a pergunta.

Comment: Sure! Não é muito difícil usar. Você vai gostar da tecnologia.

Comment: Com certeza irei, estou pesquisando a fundo... vi videos de utilização e também vi do que é capaz... muito interessante e também vou utilizar muito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi @Luiz Ricardo Cardoso,

Como falamos o que você precisa é de ***WebSocket Protocol***. Um tecnologia não apenas muito divertida como também poderosa.

Aqui está o link oficial da tecnologia que está vinculada diretamente com **HTML 5**

https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html

Neste próximo link você vai encontrar uma excelente documentacão/tutorial utilizando Spring MVC

[WebSockets com Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Bom, precisa de algo em português? Just got it!

[Material em Português - Jetty + Java + WebSockets](http://blog.caelum.com.br/websockets-html5-em-java-com-jetty-web-em-tempo-real/)

**Existe alguma JSR para o uso de WebSockets em Java?**

Sim: [JSR 356](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html)

**Quais são suas caracteristicas desta JSR?**

- Programacão dirigida a anotacões, permitindo a desenvolvedores usar
  POJOs com os ciclos de vida dos eventos WebSocket
- Programacão dirigida a interfaces(implementar interfaces), permitindo
  a desenvolvedores usar POJOs com os ciclos de vida dos eventos
  WebSocket
- Integracão com outras tecnologias Java EE - você pode injetar objetos
  e EJBs tais como Contexts e Dependency Injection

Hope you enjoy.

Não posso deixar de falar do lado do client! ;)

De uma olhada também no AngularJS para contrucao de sua aplicacao(não é essencial saber AngularJS, mas talvez você ache interessante).

Comment: Muito bom, isso é tudo e com adicionais! Solucionado a questão, obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz em saber que deu certo, essa é a importância da comunidade! Sucesso @LuizRicardoCardoso !